# Send a value from Default.aspx.cs page to Default.aspx page javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

It says VM145:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: balance is not defined.

i have declared balance as: 
        protected string balance as a class variable.

Default.aspx.cs page

```
    Response.Write("print_file(balance);");
```

Default.aspx javascript function

```
    function print_file(balance) {            
            alert("balance value is: " + balance);
            hide_innactive();
        }
```

I have tried this but the alert box returns empty

```
     function print_file() {
        var bal = "<%= balance %>";
        alert(bal);}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this in your code behind.

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PrintFile", "print_file('" + your parameter+ "');", true);
```

Comment: I put that in my aspx.cs page to replace the Response.Write statement (if that's what i'm supposed to do?) and the value in the alert box was just empty.

Comment: what parameter are you passing? You should check your parameter first whether it has some value or not?

Comment: I checked and assigned a value string of hello there just to test and it still says: Uncaught ReferenceError: balance is not defined
    at eval (eval at xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: can you show me the code how you are setting balance value?